# Open Phonegap app from Facebook share

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I have a Phonegap app with a Facebook share function.
When a user post an item from my app and another user clicks on the post (from Facebook app) it needs to open my app (if he installed it), but instead it opens the browser.

Maybe you can help me understand the process and give some ideas how to solve it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass play store or app store URL instead of your site URL . If the app is istalled in user device it will open the app otherwise open play store or app store to install your app.

Phonegap social sharing plugin link :
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin